# How do I use this external non VUE library in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I struggling to link & run this library:

https://github.com/kevinoes/page-slider-js

in VUE.js as a plugin, here is my demo code. I'm getting error slider is not defined.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-wi8p3

Comment: Why don't you just use [the official Vue.js component for fullPage](https://alvarotrigo.com/vue-fullpage/#page3)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy because I've noticed performance issues while resizing. This library is very bloated.